# GWT: Cannot read property reuseLoaderConfig of null

Tags: javascript, gwt, gwt-ext

We've a GWT-EXT application, with detailed JavaScript flag turned on for the GWT compiler, we see the following error:

```
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'com_sencha_gxt_data_shared_loader_Loader_reuseLoadConfig' of null
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_StackTraceCreator_createStackTrace__Lcom_google_gwt_core_client_JsArrayString_2(0.js@141)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_StackTraceCreator$CollectorChrome_fillInStackTrace__Ljava_lang_Throwable_2V(0.js@11)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_StackTraceCreator_fillInStackTrace__Ljava_lang_Throwable_2V(0.js@134)
    at Unknown.java_lang_Throwable_$fillInStackTrace__Ljava_lang_Throwable_2Ljava_lang_Throwable_2(0.js@3)
    at Unknown.java_lang_Throwable_$$init__Ljava_lang_Throwable_2V(0.js@3)
    at Unknown.java_lang_Throwable_Throwable__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_Throwable_2V(0.js@3)
    at Unknown.java_lang_Exception_Exception__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_Throwable_2V(0.js@77)
    at Unknown.java_lang_RuntimeException_RuntimeException__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_Throwable_2V(0.js@77)
    at Unknown.com_google_web_bindery_event_shared_UmbrellaException_UmbrellaException__Ljava_util_Set_2V(0.js@91)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_event_shared_UmbrellaException_UmbrellaException__Ljava_util_Set_2V(0.js@94)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_event_shared_HandlerManager_$fireEvent__Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_HandlerManager_2Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_GwtEvent_2V(0.js@13)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_user_client_ui_Widget_$fireEvent__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_ui_Widget_2Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_GwtEvent_2V(0.js@128)
    at Unknown.com_sencha_gxt_widget_core_client_Component_$fireEvent__Lcom_sencha_gxt_widget_core_client_Component_2Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_GwtEvent_2V(0.js@3)
    at Unknown.com_sencha_gxt_widget_core_client_Component_$show__Lcom_sencha_gxt_widget_core_client_Component_2V(0.js@5)
    at Unknown.com_sencha_gxt_widget_core_client_Component_show__V(0.js@3)
    at Unknown.com_sencha_gxt_widget_core_client_Component_$setVisible__Lcom_sencha_gxt_widget_core_client_Component_2ZV(0.js@23)
    at Unknown.com_sencha_gxt_widget_core_client_Component_setVisible__ZV(0.js@3)
    at
```

How to troubleshoot this error?

Comment: Do you get this exception in compiled mode or dev mode?

Comment: This seems to indicate that loader config is null for the loader. I think you must get this exception in dev mode (giving java stacktrace) also if you re-run the same scenario.

Comment: how do I set loader config ?

Comment: You can drill into the source of com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.loader.Loader class in GXT library. GXT source will be present in the JAR as it is required by GWT for compilation.